# StructureMap LifeCycleIs new ThreadLocalStorageLifeCycle is not thread local?

Tags: c#, multithreading, structuremap, thread-local-storage

I am trying to store two instances of the same type in two different threads using StructureMap. Each thread should have it's own instance:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ThatObjectFactoryReturnsDifferentTypesFromTwoThreadsWhenConfiguredThreadLocalStorage()
    {
        var t = new Thread(ConfigureThreadLocalStorageTest1);
        ITestObjectFactory test2 = new Test2();
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ITestObjectFactory>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle()).Use(test2));

        t.Start();
        t.Join();
        test2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>();

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(test2, typeof(Test2));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(_staticTest, typeof(Test1));
    }

    static void ConfigureThreadLocalStorageTest1()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>());
        ITestObjectFactory test1 = new Test1();
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ITestObjectFactory>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle()).Use(test1));

        _staticTest = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>();
    }
}

public class Test2 : ITestObjectFactory
{
}


public class Test1 : ITestObjectFactory
{
}

public interface ITestObjectFactory
{
}
```

However, the above test fails. Also, using the LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorage()) configuration, I would expect the ObjectFactory.GetInstance() method in the ConfigureThreadLocalStorageTest1 to return null?

Comment: Would be nice if you could click Accept if my response answers your question! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are seeing this because you are reconfiguring your `ITestObjectFactory` mapping. You are calling `ObjectFactory.Configure` for `ITestObjectFactory` twice, and the second time you do, StructureMap no longer takes into account how you configured this mapping the first time.

Therefore, when you do `test2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>();` after `t.Join();` StructureMap gives you `test1` (of class `Test1`) since that's how it's been configured last.

It would probably make more sense to write a test that configures the mapping just once, and use class-based configuration rather than configure the mapping to a specific instance. I.e `ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ITestObjectFactory>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle()).Use<YourConcreteClass>();`

**EDIT**

I've modified your code as per the above, and indeed, it passes!

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ThatObjectFactoryReturnsDifferentTypesFromTwoThreadsWhenConfiguredThreadLocalStorage()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<ITestObjectFactory>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle()).Use<Test>());
        var test1 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>();

        var t = new Thread(ConfigureThreadLocalStorageTest1);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        var test2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>();

        Assert.AreSame(test1, test2);
        Assert.AreNotSame(test1, _staticTest);
    }

    static void ConfigureThreadLocalStorageTest1()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>());
        _staticTest = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestObjectFactory>();
    }

    private static ITestObjectFactory _staticTest;

    public class Test : ITestObjectFactory
    {
    }

    public interface ITestObjectFactory
    {
    }
```